# Mouse over get the value of the link using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to get the value `mysite.com/Mycontrollername/Myactionname?dId=12&tID=2` when mouse over on the link below :

```
  <%: Html.ActionLink("test", "Myactionname", "Mycontrollername", 
  new { dId = 12,tID = 2 }, null)%>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selectedcategory').mouseover(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selectedcategory').mouseenter(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Further reading:

- [mouseenter event](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)
- [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selectedcategory').mouseover(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

ok i get it you removed the class from the anchor tag, you have two options either add a `mouseover` event handler to every anchor tag like

```
$('a').mouseover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).text()=='test')
      console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/24LEY/5/)

or you filter the anchor tag that has the text "`test`" like

```
 $('a').filter(function(){return $(this).text()=='test'}).mouseover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/24LEY/4/)

Comment: i couldn't get you arent you trying to get the `href` property of anchor tag that the `ActionLink` is producing